# Getting the code of a Redis script using the sha value

Tags: redis

Is it possible to return the script that was loaded into Redis through `SCRIPT LOAD` using the SHA value?

Answer (score 0):

No, currently (v6.x) there isn't. There's an open PR (https://github.com/redis/redis/pull/4646) if you want to add your feedback there.